# Organic Social YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api

Currently, we are in the process of building out our database with our data engineers.

We wonder if YouTube provides API for all organic social data?
•   If it does have an API connection, what are some of the information we need to provide our data engineers to set up the connection? And is there a step-by-step guide somewhere that we can follow?
•   If not, is there a way to set up some sort of scheduled report that automatically sends us reports every day or every week through email?

Haven't tried anything, don't know where to start.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics) and [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

Comment: Just wanted to follow up. Are these API connector for Organic social data only? or this is Paid social data?

Comment: To be honest I am not familiar with *ogranic social data* and *paid social data* notions. As far as I know you have a default quota per day for free and you can request and obtain a quota extension for free ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) and [quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost))